# Как прервать цепочку запросов?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть два текстовых поля и две кнопки:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="Script/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Script/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Script/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Script/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Script/jquery.ui.tabs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Script/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Script/jquery.ui.dialog.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Script/jquery.ui.button.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Script/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Script/jquery.ui.resizable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Script/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="oldShifr" class="oldShifr" />
<input type="button" value="..." id="selectShifrOld" />
<input class="newShifr" type="text" id="newShifr" />
<input type="button" value="..." id="selectShifrNew" />
```

По клику на кнопку открывается диалог. Внутри этого диалога находится `ListView`. По клику на строку `ListView` диалог закрывается и выводится сообщение о том, что нажали.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var t, d;
    t = $('.DirectoryReplaceCenmat').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "paging": false,
        "destroy": true,
        "scrollY": 500,
        "ordering": false
    });
    function crDialog() {
        d = $('#directoryReplaceCenmat').dialog({
            'width': 1500,
            modal: true
        });
    }
    $('#selectShifrNew').on('click', function() {
        crDialog();
        t.on('click', 'tr', function() {
            alert("SelectNewShfr");     
            $('#directoryReplaceCenmat').dialog("close");
        });
    });
    $('#selectShifrOld').on('click', function() {
        crDialog();
        t.on('click', 'tr', function() {
            alert("SelectOldShifr");          
            $('#directoryReplaceCenmat').dialog("close");
        });
    });
});
```

Проблема в том, что при повторном открытии диалога прослеживается вся цепочка события `click`.

Пробовал после `alert("SelectNewShifr")` и `alert("SelectOldShifr")` делать `event.stoppropagation()`. Не знаю правильно или нет, но не помогло.

В чем я ошибся?  Должно работать в браузерах: *IE 8+*, *Firefox*, *Chrome*.

Comment: Копай в сторону `unbind()`.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На каждый `$('#selectShifrNew').on('click', ...` Вы добавляете новый обработчик `t.on('click', 'tr', ...` - они накапливаются и выстреливают все, чем дальше - тем больше. Вынесите `t.on('click', 'tr', ...` из `$('#selectShifrNew').on('click', ...`. Аналогично - для `$('#selectShifrOld').on('click', ...`